# Issue Log in vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with a log in... Well let me explain you my problem, the problem is that i want to create a log in with restrictions, I have some textbox with the binding source property changed to my database. But when I type something that is not in the DataBase the program got freezes, I will post my code, hope you can help me (=

```
Private Sub KryptonButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                                 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
            Handles KryptonButton1.Click

    If txtUser.Text <> UserTextBox.Text Then
        While txtUser.Text <> UserTextBox.Text
            Me.UsuarioContraseñaBindingSource.MoveNext()
        End While
        If txtUser.Text = UserTextBox.Text Then
            KryptonMessageBox.Show("Welcome")
        Else
            KryptonMessageBox.Show("Error")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a closer look at the loop in your code and its exit condition … under what circumstances does the loop exit? What happens otherwise?

In general you need play out and cover all scenarios but you already know the scenario here: your user input is not in the database and the application freezes. This should provide ample hints to find the cause.

Comment: So... you think I could use the Exit While and put and If? You think it cn works?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
        If txt_user.Text <> vbNullString And txt_pass.Text <> vbNullString Then
            Dim chkcmd As New SqlCommand("select * from users where username = '" & txt_user.Text & "' and password = '" & txt_pass.Text & "'", con)
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
            con.Open()
            Dim chkval As SqlDataReader = chkcmd.ExecuteReader
            If chkval.Read = True Then
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
            Else
                MsgBox("Invalid key to login!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Message")
                txt_pass.Clear()
                txt_user.Clear()
                txt_user.Select()
            End If
            con.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```